# Обращение по ссылке python

Tags: python, переменные, ссылки

Допустим у меня есть следующий код:

```
a = 10
b = id(a)
```

как мне присвоить некой переменной значение переменной a, используя значение, хранящиеся в переменной b?

Comment: А можно поинтересоваться, зачем это нужно?

Comment: А что вам это даст?

Comment: Например, возможность объяснить вам, что вы хотите странного и нормальные люди делают иначе

Comment: Допустим, я странный

Answer (score 0):

Странное желание, но можно попробовать через `globals` или `locals` в зависимости от области видимости переменной:

```
a = 10
b = id(a)

print(a)

globs = globals().copy()
for key in globs:
    if id(globs[key]) == b:
        globals()[key] = 20

print(a)
```